# Deploying C# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have developed a C# winform app in VS 2012, but when I deploy it to another machine, it's exe file does not launch until and unless the machine has VS 2012 installed in it. Initially I thought there was a problem with deployment, but I have tried all methods, by simply transferring the bin folder to creating a setup project using installShield, I tried deploying a simple app which was successful without having to install VS 2012. Could someone please give me the reason behind this dependency of my app with VS 2012, and how to get rid of it? I cannot afford to install a VS 2012 on every machine that the software needs to deployed to. Thank you so much.

Comment: Which version of .NET is installed on target machine? Does it match with .NET version, required for your application?

Comment: Yes Dennis, there is no problem with the .net framework, that I am sure of, because initially it used to say .net 4.5 and higher required, which I had installed, and after that no error pops up, just that the software doesnt launch

Answer (score 1):

This is all about which .Net Framework is installed on the machine.

For Instance, VS2012 will run on .Net Framework 4.5, but the computer your trying to run this software on maybe running on an earlier version.

If any of the assemblies that your adding to your solution are built on a later version of the .Net framework then it will be incompatible on the users machine.

Answer (score 0):

change Your project Debug mode to Release Mode Then Run The App then Go to >Bin > Release Folder then u can Find Exc Setup !! Have Fun with Code !!

Answer (score -1):

Probably your app depends on some assembly that is installed along with VS. You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out exactly what. On second thought, since this is a .Net application your dependencies should be limited to .Net assemblies and the .Net framework - you could find out exactly what you're missing on the target machine with [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/).

Comment: Dependency Walker is almost useless for .NET assemblies.

Comment: @Dennis, true that. I should suggest dotPeek